Does sorting reduce MySQL deadlock likelihood of INSERT/UPDATE batches?
We know that MySQL INSERT/ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statements create gap locks which may lead to deadlocks between multiple threads.
If the INSERT/UPDATE is done in batches (either in a separate transaction for each batch or all batches in the same transaction), do we reduce the likelihood of deadlocks by sorting the data first?
Here's an example where that seems to be the case, but I don't understand why.

https://github.com/fleetdm/fleet/issues/1146#issuecomment-865134315
CREATE TABLE for the above example:

CREATE TABLE `label_membership` (
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `label_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `host_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`host_id`,`label_id`),
  KEY `idx_lm_label_id` (`label_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_lm_host_id` FOREIGN KEY (`host_id`) REFERENCES `hosts` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_lm_label_id` FOREIGN KEY (`label_id`) REFERENCES `labels` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


Full schema: https://github.com/fleetdm/fleet/blob/8b4c6a1dd7d2683b9e7e6ebe22f372f0a419e6d8/server/datastore/mysql/schema.sql#L266


multiple bulk inserts are not a good idea as you already noticed, especially in a multiple client. is it possible to a make instead of a transactions with for insert a transaction for every insert instead. So that every process has a chance at least to insert data and has not to waut till the other transaction finishes

Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE for the table involved.

@RickJames I added the CREATE TABLE statement.

@nbk I'm sorry, I don't quite understand your comment. Are you saying each insert/update statement should be its own transaction?

@VictorL - A single statement is a transaction unto itself.  So, BEGIN; one stmt; COMMIT; is OK, but overkill.  In many cases, BEGIN; SELECT..FOR UPDATE; write; COMMIT; is necessary.

@RickJames I don't see the benefit of SELECT ... FOR UPDATE here -- if the row does not exist, then MySQL will still do a gap lock, which could lead to a deadlock.

Regardless of the cause, check for deadlock (and lock_wait_timeout) and replay the query.

Back to the title -- sorting may reduce the frequency of deadlocks.
